# subir imagen formulario php y guardar ruta en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Quiero cargar una foto mediante un formulario. Guardarla en mi carpeta img y que en la base de datos guarde solo la ruta.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$dir="img/";
$nombreArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['name'];

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$dir.$nombreArchivo)){
    echo "error en la subida de la foto";
    echo "<a href='../views/empleadoAltaFormulario.php'>Volver</a>";
    exit;
}

$foto = $empleado->setFoto($nombreArchivo);
```

En la base de datos me guarda la ruta correctamente. El problema está en que la imagen no se guarda en ningún sitio. Creo que estoy indicando mal la ruta. Este sería mi árbol:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código lo tengo en "empleadoControlador" y quiero guardar la imagen la carpeta "img".

Otra solución que he probado es esta que he cogido de la documentación oficial. Aunque esto no me guarda ni la imagen ni la ruta en la BBDD:

```
    $dir_subida = '../img/';
$fichero_subido = $dir_subida.basename($_FILES['foto']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $fichero_subido)) {
    echo "El fichero es válido y se subió con éxito.\n";
} else {
    echo "¡Posible ataque de subida de ficheros!\n";
}
```

He comprobado que el archivo llega al controlador correctamente de la siguiente manera:

```
    $dir='img/';
$nombreArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['name'];

// Si no existe el directorio lo creas

if ( !is_dir( $dir . $nombreArchivo ) ){
  mkdir($dir . $nombreArchivo);
}

// Ahora puedes mover la imagen al directorio

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$dir)){
echo "nombre: " .$_FILES['foto']['name']."<br>";
echo "ruta temporal: ".$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']."<br>";
echo "tipo archivo: ".$_FILES['foto']['type']."<br>";
echo "tamaño: ".$_FILES['foto']['size']."<br>";
echo "errores: ".$_FILES['foto']['error']."<br>";
    echo "error en la subida de la foto<br>";
    echo "<a href='../views/empleadoAltaFormulario.php'>Volver</a>";
    exit;
}
```

Esto es lo que me imprime:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi archivo php.ini me he encontrado con que tenía limitado el tamaño del archivo a 2MB y el de todo el post a 8MB. Lo he cambiado todo a 32MB como se puede ver en las imágenes, sin embargo, el problema persiste y el número de errores sigue siendo 0.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

No te guarda la imagen porque tratas de guardarla en $dir.$nombreArchivo (carpeta que no existe), deberias hacer un comprobación y si no existe crearla de forma dinámica.
ejemplo:

```
$dir="img/";
$nombreArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['name'];

// Si no existe el directorio lo creas

if ( !is_dir( $dir . $nombreArchivo ) ){
  mkdir($dir . $nombreArchivo);
}

// Ahora puedes mover la imagen al directorio

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$dir.$nombreArchivo)){
    echo "error en la subida de la foto";
    echo "<a href='../views/empleadoAltaFormulario.php'>Volver</a>";
    exit;
}

$foto = $empleado->setFoto($nombreArchivo);
```

Si lo que quieres es guardarla directamente en img simplemente quita el .$nombreArchivo:

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$dir) ){
    echo "error en la subida de la foto";
    echo "<a href='../views/empleadoAltaFormulario.php'>Volver</a>";
    exit;
}
```

#### nota:

La ruta debe ser como la tienes en un principio 'img/' y no como en el ejemplo de la documentacion oficial que pusiste ('../img'), ya que por lo que veo tu página carga de forma dinámica desde el index, si es asi y la llamada la haces desde el index ( se encuentra en la raiz ) debe ser directamente 'img/'

### Editado:

Aunque el cod de error es 0 (sin eror) asegurate de que el archivo no es mayor que el límite que tienes establecido.

Pueba a subir una imagen de un tamaño pequeño a ver si así si que te lo permite, de ser así debes aumentar los siguientes valores en tu php.ini:

```
// Limite de tamaño del archivo (Segun tus necesidades)
upload_max_filesize = 32M
```

y

```
// Determina la carga total (por ejemplo si son varios ficheros en un solo envio) 
//debe ser mayor o igual al tamaño máximo de subida del archivo.
post_max_size = 32M
```

Si debes hacer esto recuerda reiniciar el servidor tras modificarlo.

Comment: Hola! gracias por el aporte pero sigue sin funcionar. He puesto comillas simples en la ruta para ver si era eso y también he probado tanto con 'img/' como con '../img/' No entiendo lo que puede estar pasando...

Comment: He comprobado también si es un problema de permisos pero no. He dado permisos de lectura y escritura a todos y sigue igual.

Comment: Has comprobado el valor de $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'] justo antes de entrar en la condicion? @jorgeGarciaCano

Comment: Sí. Arriba puedes ver que he añadido una pequeña comprobación para ver si los datos del formulario llegaban al controlador.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta tras ver tu actualizacion de la pregunta a ver si te ayuda @jorgeGarciaCano

Comment: Gracias Chema. He vuelto a actualizar la respuesta. He modificado los valores en php.ini pero sigue imprimiendo lo mismo. Número de errores 0. He probado con toras imágenes y también he reiniciado el servidor.

Comment: SOLUCIONADO. El problema era cuestión de  permisos de  la  carpeta img. Comprobé los  permisos  de  la carpeta del  proyecto,  pero no de esta.  Siento  las molestias. Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que no se que sistema operativo estas usando, asumo que debe ser linux por vscode y que estas trabajando en localhost asi que te comprato posibles soluciones para sistemas linux.

Posibles soluciones:

**Opcion 1:** Validar en la configuracion de php.ini la directiva **fileUploads = On** Si usas linux para saber su ruta puede ejecutar el siguiente comando

```
php --ini
```

Esto dara como resultado una lista de los archivos de configuracion. debes buscar el que dice:

**Loaded Configuration File:**         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini

**Opcion 2:** Verificar el codigo HTML. Recordar que el metodo debe de ser POST y que deber usar el atributo **enctype="multipart/form-data"** y no el urlformencoded que se usa con los formularios normales de datos. Tambien verifcar que el input debe tener el atributo **type="file"**.

**Opcion 3:** Verificar que el directorio donde quieres guardar las imagenes tiene permisos de escritura y pertenece al grupo de www-data

```
sudo chown $USER:www-data uploads
sudo chmod 777 uploads
```

Nota: Si otorgas permisos de 777 es un areglo temporal la verdad no soy experto en cuestion de permisos en sistemas unix pero siempre debes buscar el minimo de permisos o por lo menos quitar los permisos de ejecucion ya que si lo haces asi podrian subir un codigo y luego ejecutarlo o algo asi, indaga mas al respecto pero por mientras puedes trabajar en tu maquina local con permisos de 777 aunque no es recomendable para entornos de produccion.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar la varaible `$dir` por:

```
$dir = __DIR__ . '../img/';
```

Comment: Nada, entra en el condicional e imprime el error "error en la subida de la foto".

Comment: he visto en internet, que le ponen un @ antes de la funcion: @move_uploaded_file, intenta a ver...

Comment: Tampoco funciona. En la documentación oficial hay un ejemplo que también he probado y nada...